# When i export (save feature as) a polygon in QGIS it converts to a multipoint and multipolygon how do i stop this

Tags: qgis, polygon, error, multipoint

Im using QGIS and I have a property boundaries .shp When I try to export this using the 'save feature as' option the resulting shpfile has missing poylgons and it has converted itself into multipoints and multipolygon, this happens even if I change the geometry to polygon. This is the error i get:
"Export to vector file failed.
Error: Feature write errors:
Feature creation error (OGR error: Attempt to write non-polygon (MULTIPOINT) geometry to POLYGON type shapefile.)."

I'm using 3.28.6 LTR but have tried with 3.30 and still get the same issue have tried using multipart to singlepart this allows me to export but is there a way to fix this without having to run the multipart to singlepart function every time.

Comment: You may have hidden geometry errors.  Run the **Fix Geometries** tool on your source data, and then try the export on the tool's output.

Comment: Try to apply a small buffer, than buffer again by the same, but this time negative value. Does this work? Sometimes even buffering with a distance of 0 helps. Otherwise, as mentioned by @StuSmith repair the geometries using Geometry Checker and Topology checker (if not activated, activate it under menu plugins; then you find in in menu Vector).

Comment: What you experience should not happen, but if others would like to reproduce the error you should share some test data and all the steps that you do with QGIS. What you can do is to download some free dataset and try to edit and save that.